# Regenerate pkg-config file `opencv.pc` without recompiling

Tags: opencv, makefile, cmake, compilation, pkg-config

I compiled the OpenCV library (version 4) on Raspbian with the following commands in a subdirectory I created:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./ -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../
make -j4
make install
```

and I was using the pkg-config file `opencv.pc` to compile a project with a `Makefile`.

I had to move the library folder to another directory so the file `opencv.pc` points to wrong paths. However the dynamic libraries should be still valid (shouldn't they?).

So how can regenerate the `opencv.pc` file without recompiling the all library on Raspbian which takes a lot of time?

**EDIT 1**
Trying to rerun `cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./ -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../`  results in the following error:

```
CMake Error: The current CMakeCache.txt directory /home/pi/opencv-2.4.13/build/CMakeCache.txt is different than the directory /home/pi/OldDirectory/opencv-2.4.13/build/ where CmakeCache.txt was created. This may result in binaries being created in the wrong place. If you are not sure reedit CMakeCache.txt 
CMake Error The source "NewSourcePath" does not match the source "NewSourcePath" used to generate cache. Re-run cmake with a different source directory.
```

Comment: Usually, `.pc` files are generated on *configuration* stage. It will be sufficient to run `cmake` with the proper install prefix (and some other parameters), find this file in the build tree and copy it into install one.

Comment: Trying to rerunning `cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./ -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../
` results in an error  about the CMakeCache.txt file: should I remove it?

Comment: If `CMakeCache.txt` is in the *source* tree, you need to remove it for out-of-source builds. Otherwise, just choose another (empty) directory as a build one. (Note, that last argument for `cmake` is a path to the source dir, you may need to correct it when use new build directory).

Comment: It seems that you have copied a build directory, but in CMake **build directory is not relocatable**, so its copy doesn't work. This is what CMake tells you in the error messages. Just clean the new build directory and repeat.

Comment: even if I delete the build directory `cmake` is returning an error: `RegularExpression::compile(): error in compile CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:90 (if): if given arguments:  "NewSourcePath"

Comment: Such messages indicates that you do something weird, but you don't describe what exactly you are doing: which directories you have, where you call `cmake`, etc. What is `NewSourcePath`? Is it an actual string, or is it shorcut for something? Did you copy just a build tree, or source tree too? (No needs to copy them).

Comment: Actually it seemed that I moved the folder inside a folder named `C++libs` and `cmake` does not seem to like folder names with +.

Answer (score 0):

> I had to move the library folder to another directory so the file opencv.pc points to wrong paths. However the dynamic libraries should be still valid (shouldn't they?).

Your `.pc` file should use paths relative to its own location. That way, it can be safely relocated. For example,

```
prefix=${pcfiledir}/../..
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${prefix}/include
includedir=${prefix}/lib64

Name: Proton
Description: Qpid Proton C library
Version: 0.36.0
URL: http://qpid.apache.org/proton/
Libs: -L${libdir} -lqpid-proton
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

The trick is the `${pcfiledir}` variable. Therefore, well-written `.pc` file will 'just work'. If the file uses absolute path, you can get away with a find-and-replace approach, where you replace the prefix pointing to the previous library location with the new prefix where you have the library now.

Source: https://indico.cern.ch/event/848215/contributions/3591953/attachments/1923018/3181752/HSFPackagingRelocation.pdf